# Play Framework 1.2.7 Add select tag to form tag as input field

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have 2 models, Course and Department. Course belong to Department so what I am trying to do is at Course Creation page, in the form, I am trying to display all the Departments in the select tag so the user can choose 1. 
Here is my code

```
#{form @Courses.save(), id:'createUser'}
<div>
   Course Name: <input type="text" name="courseName"  />
</div>
<div>
  Course Department: #{select 'departments',name:'department', items:departments, valueProperty:'id', labelProperty:'DepartmentName',  class:"Departments", id:'select Departments', form='createUser' /} 
</div>
<div>
   <input type="submit" value="Create Course" /> 
</div>

#{/form}
```

I get an error saying `Unexpected node type: EXPR found when expecting type: LABELED_ARG at line: 10 column: 166. File: /app/views/Courses/create.html`. This is the `Course Department` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake. `form='createUser'` should have been `form:createUser`. Woops

Answer (score 0):

In your **#{select}** tag, the id parameter should not have any spaces in it. So

```
... id : 'select-departments' ...
```

Comment: Actually the problem was with the "=" sign. should have been a ":"